# How to update Apache's PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-17.10

I installed Laravel 5.6, but it's not working because it requires PHP 7.2.
I use Ubuntu 17, and installed Apache 2 and PHP 7.2 (7.1, 7.0) but when I use `phpinfo()` it shows php7.0.
So how can I config Apache and set php7.2 instead of php7.0?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after installing PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first you have to install `php7.2` with the following commands

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y php7.2
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-curl php7.2-intl php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-json php7.2-bz2 php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-mbstring  php7.2-soap php7.2-xml php7.2-zip
```

After installing php you have to run the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php "/usr/bin/php7.2";
sudo update-alternatives --set "php-config" "/usr/bin/php-config7.2";
sudo a2dismod "php7.0"
sudo a2dismod "php5.6"
sudo a2enmod "php7.2"
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you installed `php7.2-dev` then you should run the following command too:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set "phpize" "/usr/bin/phpize7.2";
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to have `PHP 7.2` installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli
```

After that, you can run the command below to see the installed version of PHP:

```
php -v
```